# Unable to run R png command from Java

Tags: java, r

I am trying to run some R commands within Java.  I am able to create a connection using RConnection.

Then, I send the following commands:

```
c.eval( "setwd('" + folderIn.getPath() + "')" );
c.eval( "Age = read.table('"+ filename+".txt" + "')" );     //  LOAD DATA FILE
c.eval( "Age <- as.numeric(Age)" );                         //  CONVERT TO NUMERIC
c.eval( "setwd('" + folderOut.getPath() + "')"  );          //  SET DIR
c.eval( "png('" + filename+".png" +"')" );
```

It runs fine until it gets to the 'png' line and then it returns 'eval failed'.

Interestingly, if I start R on my mac using Terminal and then do: library(Rserve) and then Rserve()  and then run my Java program, it runs fine.   However, when I start R by having java execute a script with the following:

```
R -e "library(Rserve);Rserve(FALSE,args='--no-save --slave')" --no-save --slave
```

then it can't get past the 'png' line in the code.

Anyone have any ideas on why this would be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around this problem by saving my plot in svg rather than png.   So instead of the png(..) command, I used the svg(...) command.  Works well.